# Best value-for-money hosted Centralized Logs and Metrics

Tags: monitoring, logs, log-analysis

What is a good solution for centralizing lots of log files for monitoring and analysis?

I have about 20 Linux web servers generating ~4GB of nginx and Apache log files per day.
I would like at least 30 days of logs to be retained.

I have used Sumo Logic in the past, and moved to a self hosted ELK stack, which is unfortunately no longer functioning. I am looking for a solution that will have similar analysis abilities to Kibana, and at a competitive price.

If the solution also monitors Metrics for a set of servers (i.e. CPU/Memory/Disk usage) that would be great, but I am ok with setting that up separately using Munin / NetData to save money. My main requirement is to get a good value for money tool for log file analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Although Netdata does not offer log retaining at the moment, we do have a quite powerful log parser, with a lot of charts and alarms out-of-the-box.

Here is a guide on how to set it up for NginX and Apache: https://learn.netdata.cloud/guides/collect-apache-nginx-web-logs

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. NetData is a strong choice for our metrics.

Comment: Thanks Liam! We have actually a whole community forum if you want to hop in, post your questions and have a discussion about your use-case. Join us at https://community.netdata.cloud